# $n$-th derivative change of variable

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, derivatives

I have a change of variables from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ such such that $$\frac{d}{d\beta} = \frac{1}{f(\alpha)}\frac{d}{d\alpha}$$
therfore, the second derivative will read
$$\frac{d^2}{d\beta^2} =\frac{1}{f(\alpha)}\frac{d}{d\alpha}\times \frac{1}{f(\alpha)}\frac{d}{d\alpha}= \frac{1}{f^2(\alpha)}\frac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}-\frac{f'(\alpha)}{f^3(\alpha)}\frac{d}{d\alpha}$$
and the third order reads
$$\frac{d^3}{d\beta^3} =-\frac{f''(\alpha)}{f^4(\alpha)}\frac{d}{d\alpha}+\frac{3 f'^2(\alpha)}{f^5(\alpha)}\frac{d}{d\alpha}-\frac{3 f'(\alpha)}{f^4(\alpha)}\frac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}+\frac{1}{f^3(\alpha)} \frac{d^3}{d\alpha^3}$$
I need to find the $n$-th derivative in $\beta$:
$$\frac{d^n}{d\beta^n} =\, ?$$
is there a general formula for this case?

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\frac{d^2}{d\beta^2} = \frac{1}{f^2(\alpha)}\frac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}-\frac{f'(\alpha)}{f^3(\alpha)}\frac{d}{d\alpha}$?

Comment: For the composite function,
$$\frac {d^n} {d\beta^n} g(\alpha) =
\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} g^{(k)}(\alpha)
 B_{n, k}(\alpha', \ldots, \alpha^{(n - k + 1)}).$$
For the inverse function, since $\beta^{(n)}(\alpha) = f^{(n - 1)}(\alpha)$,
$$\alpha^{(n)} =
\frac 1 {f^n(\alpha)} \sum_{1 \leq k < n}
 \frac {(-1)^k (n)_k} {f^k(\alpha)} B_{n - 1, k} {\left(
  \frac {f'(\alpha)} 2, \ldots,
  \frac {f^{(n - k)}(\alpha)} {n - k + 1} \right)},$$
where $B_{n, k}$ are the Bell polynomials and $(n)_k$ is the rising factorial.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, known as Leibnitz formula. It gives the $n^{\text{th}} $ derivative of a product

$$(F.G)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}F^{(k)}G^{(n-k)}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but the formula doesn't even reproduce the example I provided

Comment: i think this is useful @Fra

Comment: I am afraid I don't see how